# fastapi-utils shares all dependencies between all endpoints

Tags: fastapi

I ran into a problem when I used [fastapi-utils](https://github.com/dmontagu/fastapi-utils).

Using this library you get able to make one class including a group of associated endpoints. You also can locate your dependencies in this class as its attributes.
But the problem is this dependencies will be used in each endpoint.

**Example:**

```
router = InferringRouter()


@cbv(router)
class SomeAPI:
    session_user: User = Depends(get_session_user)

    @router.get("/get_session_user_id")
    def requires_session_user(self) -> dict[str, str]:
        return {"The id of the session user": self.session_user.id}

    @router.post("/process_parameter")
    def exclude_session_user(self, some_parameter: str) -> dict[str, str]
        # Process 'some_parameter'. Some calculations, etc.
        return {"message": "The item was processed successfully."}
```

The 'exclude_session_user' will require user to be authenticated when this endpoint doesn't actually need this.

How can I exclude some dependencies from a specific endpoint? Is it possible? And if it's impossible, and someone contributed this library, why this problem isn't explained in the [documentation](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/#the-cbv-decorator)?

Comment: It's usually better to split authenticated and unauthenticated endpoints into separate routers, so that you have a clear division between what are public endpoints and what are authenticated endpoints. `class SomeAPIPublic` and `SomeAPIAuthenticated` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are asking if a feature, that is specifically designed to solve problem A, to no longer solve problem A but rather problem B. And if that is not possible, you then want someone else to explain in the documentation that this doesn't solve a problem it wasn't designed for.

In other words; no this is not possible. It is designed to give all endpoints bundled in that class, the required dependencies. If you want different combinations of dependencies, then you can either:

- Just use the normal FastAPI way and declare the dependencies you want on each endpoint (or if your dependencies do not return anything you could specify them on all endpoints in a specific router, or on your entire application!)
- Keep on using fastapi-utils, but create different classes that hold endpoints that require different combinations of dependencies.

One last note: it is ill-advised to bundle authenticated and non-authenticated calls to your API. Mistakes are easily made and endpoints that should've had authentication suddenly are open for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The fact is that I mistakenly believed that using this library, I could declare one class which is a specific part of my API, and the library, depending on endpoints that use a certain dependency, would distribute all dependencies. The issue isn't raised in the doc. - it says that you just need to create a class and place your deps. as attributes. You made it clear that authors of the lib. were probable looking in a different direction. By the way, I'm not sure that I understood the last note. Could you please introduce me with an example?